# how can i fetch the parent class primary id and store it in child's table which is stored under the user as parent in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I have hospital entity and doctor entity and doctors are registered under hospital user. i have mapped one to many unidirectional between these but when i register a doctor through a form it's Hospital Id column shows null.

this is my hospital class where i have defined various attributes and also have mapped in between them

````
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="hospital")
public class Hospital {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="hospitalid")
    private int hospital_id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="hospital",cascade={CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<HospitalDoctorEntity> doctorList;

    public List<HospitalDoctorEntity> getDoctorList() {
        return doctorList;
    }

    public void setDoctorList(List<HospitalDoctorEntity> doctorList) {
        this.doctorList = doctorList;
    }

    public int getAccount_status() {
        return account_status;
    }

    public void setAccount_status(int account_status) {
        this.account_status = account_status;
    }

    public void setHospital_id(int hospital_id) {
        this.hospital_id = hospital_id;
    }
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="hospitalname")
    private String hospitalName;
    @Column(name="addressline1")
    private String addressLine1;
    @Column(name="addressline2")
    private String addressLine2;
    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;
    @Column(name="state")
    private String state;
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name="achievements")
    private String achievements;
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="accountstatus")
    private int account_status =0;
    public int getHospital_id() {
        return hospital_id;
    }

    public String getHospitalName() {
        return hospitalName;
    }
    public void setHospitalName(String hospitalName) {
        this.hospitalName = hospitalName;
    }
    public String getAddressLine1() {
        return addressLine1;
    }
    public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    }
    public String getAddressLine2() {
        return addressLine2;
    }
    public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getAchievements() {
        return achievements;
    }
    public void setAchievements(String achievements) {
        this.achievements = achievements;
    }
}```
````

Comment: How do you expect anyone to answer this question without any code?

Comment: But just as a guess sounds like a primary key issue?

Comment: i just want to associate the primary key of the hospital with the doctor in doctor table... can you help

Comment: Add some code man.